# Excel 2010 Macros Fun with Buttons

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Ok so I am creating a spreadsheet that can be edited by another user but locked otherwise. What I am hoping to do is create 3 buttons. "What If" "Exit What if" and "Reset"

"What if" will allow for the user to input data.
"Exit what if" will allow for the user to exit the input mode and revert back to the default. document.
Then "Reset" will allow for the user stay in "What if" but reset all the values to default.

Then I want the button "What if" to appear somewhere up in the left but when you click it, its replaced by "Exit" and "Reset"

Comment: What code do you have so far? This shouldn't be a hugely difficult task, but it helps to start somewhere. :)

Comment: @Michael: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to explain a little more you question, but so far for what I can infere you have the folloing issuse:

- have a excel sheet with formulae and data locked.
- offer edit the page, but no save the changes, as "a  consult" to the data.

I can primarily offer the following:

- Create a *backup sheet* where your save you base page
- Unlock the sheet for editing.
- if you exit the editing, restore the data from the backup to the main sheet.
- if you reset the editing, do the same procedure as exit plus unlock again the data. (for how it was charted the code flow, the copied sheet has his data locked)

This will result in the followin code:

```
Sub BackUpData() 'this will be linked to you "what if" button
    Sheets("Data_Sheet").Select 'select shhet with data, just in case
    Range("A1:M56").Select ' range of your important data in your excel sheet
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("BackUp_Sheet").Select
    Range("A1").Select     'lets paste the data in the same positión
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Data_Sheet").Select
End Sub
```

This make a copy of the data and the formulas, copying charts without breaking his datasource is another problem, maybe your can elabore on this matter. Have any charts?

```
Sub RestoreData() 'this will be linked to you "Reset" and "Exit" button
    Sheets("BackUp_Sheet").Select 'select shhet with data, just in case
    Range("A1:M56").Select ' range of your important data in your excel sheet
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Data_Sheet").Select
    Range("A1").Select     'lets paste the data in the same positión
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Usual room for improvement:

- Dinamicaly select the range, but no select all the sheet, because memory isssuses may arise. (I run out of resources when try to copy all the cell of excel 2007 in my laptop :P).
- Remove flicker with **Application.ScreenUpdating**.
- I haven`t check if this work when the *backup_Sheet* is **hidden**.

The other isssuse is **unlock** the data in the sheet.

```
Sub UnlockMySheet()
        'password here won`t protect the business logic or the code from prying eyes, just the user from themselves
        ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect 
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        Range("D9,B13").Select ' select the editable cells
        Selection.Locked = False
        Selection.FormulaHidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        ActiveWorkbook.Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=True
End Sub
```

Usual room for improvement:

- Maybe I forgot the protect protocol and I`m just leaving the page exactly as it was. (sorry no time to proof this code).
- Sugestion from stackoverflow collective mind.

and that is, for now